# Microsoft.Win32.Registry's GetValue Doesn't Use Default Value

Tags: c#, 64-bit, registry

I have a legacy (I didn't build it) application running on an x64 environment (Win7). I have a sneaking suspicion it was run on a 32-bit environment before.

Anyway, I see calls to `Registry.GetValue(key, value, default)`.

It seems like the default value is ignored.

Check out this crazy code:

```
// Up above the sky, so high
using Microsoft.Win32;
// ...
string location = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\..."; // ...
// ...

string registryValue = (string)Registry.GetValue(location, "Uri", "http://localhost/");
if (string.isNullOrEmpty(registryValue) {
  throw new Exception("What the ... ?!");
}
```

In a comparable example, the exception is seriously being thrown. (Actually, a null-reference exception appears despite the default value).

And I checked that I have the registry keys all the way up to the last level; they're all in my registry.

This works for *someone*, but not for me.

Is this a bug? What's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely you are being caught out by [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You have a 32 bit process running on a 64 bit system. So `HKLM\Software` is redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

When the key does not exist, the [`Registry.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx) returns `null` rather than the default value and so the exception is thrown.

> If the name is not found in the specified key, returns a default value that you provide, or null if the specified key does not exist.

Comment: I don't see why that would make a difference. Why isn't the default value kicking in, even if that is the case?

Comment: I've included an extract of the documentation. I hadn't realised that you'd got a slight misunderstanding of what GetValue does.

Answer (score 2):

The default value is only returned if the specified key (that is the first parameter, i.e. `location` in your example) *is found* but a value with the specified name (the second parameter, `"Uri"` in your example) does not exist within that key.

If the key itself does not exist a `null` reference is returned.

This is fairly well documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx).

Probably the key you are looking for does not exist, probably because you are running on a 64-bit environment now which means that in case your application is a 32-bit process the `HKLM\Software` key gets mapped to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

Comment: So you're saying this is my bad, I assumed the default value kicks in if any sort of problem occurs, like your hard-drive bursting into flames. You're saying the default value only applies when the key is found in the registry and it's empty?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the default value only applies when the key is found and the value with the specified name does not exist within that key. (Post edited to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ancient, but in case anybody else stumbles upon this issue, I found an approach that works well for me. I'm using OpenSubKey, instead of GetValue.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyProduct");
string data = key.GetValue("MyValue") as string;
```

The registry's terminology caused me some confusion. It is not simply a key -> value store, it is more like key -> value -> data.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why but i solved using

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.GetValue("Software\Mykey","Default Value")
instead of
My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software","Mykey","Default Value")
```

If the key doesn't exist the first example returns "Default Value", the second a null object!